# Checking whether the solution satisfies the equation

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I want to check whether the solution f[u,v] satisfies the PDE. (As I know, all parameters are reals. So, I used `Assumptions` or `Assuming`. But I can't still accomplish.)

```
     \[Sigma] = 
         3*q + 2*r; 
\[Lambda] = ((-k)*p - 
            k^2*\[Theta] + \[Delta]^2*\[Theta] + 
            k^2*p*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
            p*\[Delta]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
            k^3*\[Theta]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
                 k*\[Delta]^2*\[Theta]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])/(1 - 
            2*k*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
            k^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^2 + \[Delta]^2*
             Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^2);


      \[Omega] = (2*k*\[Theta] - \[Lambda]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
         p)/(k*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 1);
f[u_, v_] := 
     -((4*Sqrt[2]*
       E^((-I)*k*u + u*\[Delta] - 
          v*\[Delta]*\[Omega] + (I*
             v*(p*(-k + (k^2 + \[Delta]^2)*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]) + 
                          \[Theta]*(-k^2 + \[Delta]^2 + 
                  k*(k^2 + \[Delta]^2)*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])))/(1 - 
             2*k*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + (k^2 + \[Delta]^2)*
              Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^2) + 
                  I*\[Phi])*\[Alpha]*
       Sqrt[\[Delta]^2*\[Chi]*(\[Theta] + 
           p*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])])/((4*
          E^(2*\[Delta]*(u - v*\[Omega]))*\[Alpha]^2 + \[Chi])*
             
       Sqrt[(b + 2*k*(q + r))*(1 - 
           2*k*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + (k^2 + \[Delta]^2)*
            Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^2)]));
pde = I D[f[u, v], v] + \[Theta] D[f[u, v], {u, 2}] + 
    Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] D[f[u, v], u, v] + 
    ComplexExpand[
      Abs[f[u, v]]^2] (b f[u, v] + I \[Sigma] D[f[u, v], u]) == 
   I (p  D[f[u, v], u] + 
      q D[ComplexExpand@(Abs[f[u, v]]^2)*f[u, v], u] + 
      r D[ComplexExpand@(Abs[f[u, v]]^2), u]*f[u, v]);


FullSimplify[pde]
```

(When I assign some values to all parameters, the solution satisfies the PDE. But without assigning parameters, I can't check whether the solution satisfies PDE. Is it necessary some more assumptions?)

Comment: You said that all parameters are reals, but you have not imposed that as a condition. Are you familiar with `Assumptions` or `Assuming`?

Comment: I used `Assumptions` or `Assuming`. But I can't still accomplish it.